# Identity check failed for outgoing message. The expected DNS identity of the remote endpoint was XXX

Tags: wcf, certificate, wif, saml

I am having problems with a WCF Service which is being authenticated via certificate. The error I get is Identity check failed for outgoing message. The expected DNS identity of the remote endpoint was xxx....

I have seen lots of posts about this and all of them say set the dns as the name / subject of the certificate.

```
<identity>
                    <dns value="WcfServer" />
                </identity>
```

I have tried this and it does not work, what else can I do?

Luke

Answer (score 2):

The DNS name should match the Common Name (CN) of the certificate.

See this other thread which is similar.
[Why does WCF complain over identity check failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629715/why-does-wcf-complain-over-identity-check-failure)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the WSDL file of the service. It'll show you the identity expected by the Service under  element. For example, like this,

```
<wsdl:service name="CalculatorService">
  <wsdl:port name="WSHttpBinding_ICalculator_Windows"
    binding="tns:WSHttpBinding_ICalculator_Windows">
    <soap12:address 
      location=
      "http://localhost:8003/servicemodelsamples/service/upnidentity" />
    <wsa10:EndpointReference>
      <wsa10:Address>
        http://localhost:8003/servicemodelsamples/service/upnidentity
      </wsa10:Address>
      <Identity  
        xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2006/02/addressingidentity">
        <Upn>username@contoso.com</Upn>
      </Identity>
    </wsa10:EndpointReference>
  </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Based on the identity chosen by service, you can set it in client endpoint.

HTH,
Amit