# WCF and Wildcard Certificates with NetTcp binding

Tags: c#, wcf, dns, certificate, net.tcp

I have a self hosted WCF service using a NetTcp binding and TransportWithMessageCredential security with a wildcard cert (*.company.com) as the service certificate.

The client address of the server is (ServerName.company.com) I get the following error when a service call is made:

> Identity check failed for outgoing message. The expected DNS identity of the remote endpoint was 'ServerName.company.com' but the remote endpoint provided DNS claim '*.company.com'. If this is a legitimate remote endpoint, you can fix the problem by explicitly specifying DNS identity '*.company.com' as the Identity property of EndpointAddress when creating channel proxy.

Is this actually possible? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you add your configuration ?

Comment: There is a similar question with answers over here: [WCF Identity Check](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1630238/2661476)

Comment: This could also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24385815/wcf-over-https-using-a-wildcard-ssl-certificate

Comment: Please post the code you are making this call with,