# C# How to change EndpointIdentity in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, servicehost

Is ServiceHost able to change EndpointIdentity?I wrote below code, but EndpointIdentity' never changed.

```
var aa = host.AddServiceEndpoint(
                 typeof(IDuplexService),
                 netTcpBinding2,
                 "");

            Uri dnsrelativeAddress = new Uri(host.BaseAddresses[0], "duplex");
```

The servicehost's Certification'dns name is "sample.com", but I want to change dnsidentity like "identity.com". Because the client's already released and I can't renew dnsidentity easily.

Can I change dnsIdentity Forcibly?

・Certifacate set Code

```
                var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, location);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            X509Certificate2 cert = store.Certificates.OfType<X509Certificate2>().FirstOrDefault(
                x => x.Thumbprint == thumbprint
            );
            store.Close();

            host.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Certificate = cert;
            EndpointAddress epa = new EndpointAddress(dnsrelativeAddress, EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("identity.com"));
            aa.Address= epa;
```

Comment: As far as I know, there is no problem changing DNSIdentity code. However, make sure that the identity on the client and server is the same.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.I got the error message like this post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629715/why-does-wcf-complain-over-identity-check-failure
This post's also written like 'if your production server is going to be in "production.yourcompany.com", the certificate needs to be made out to that domain.'
Can I change dnsidentity?
I set endpointidentity but , never changed.

Comment: Maybe you can refer to the code of the highest scoring answer in the above post.